# Will updating Azure static public IP from Basic to Standard SKU reassign a new IP address?

Tags: azure, static-ip

as per the title. I have an Azure VM with a Basic SKU static public IP and considering to upgrade it to the standard. However, I do not wish the IP to change as it's being whitelisted in various of our partners systems. It seems I need to disassiocate it first before I'm able to upgrade it to Standard. That's what's worrying me that I might be changed/reassigned a new IP from their public pool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating from a basic to a standard SKU should NOT change the current static IP address. I have done this plenty of times before. Disassociate the Public IP with the NIC, make the upgrade, reassociate with the NIC again and you're set.

You could also use an optional DNS name on the public IP or set up Azure DNS to allow for custom domain use, unless your partners have a specific requirement to whitelist by IP only.